# Not getting data from HTML using python scraping

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping

Hi :) I'm trying to get some dividend history data for a certain share from a website by using some web scraping. Since I just started with python, I'm having a hard time getting the data. Here is a sample code that i'm trying to go through.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

isin_key = 'DE0008404005'

url = 'https://www.boersen-zeitung.de/index.php?li=24&l=0&isin={}'.format(isin_key)
html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table")
table_data = table.find_all('td', attrs={"class": "text"})
```

From that point I'm get following:

`[<td class="text"><div align="left">07.05.20</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">9,600000000 EUR</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">Laufende Dividende</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">Geschäftsjahr</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">06.05.20</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="left">09.05.19</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">9,000000000 EUR</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">Laufende Dividende</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">Geschäftsjahr</div></td>, <td class="text"><div align="right">08.05.19</div></td>`,

I don't know how to extract the ex-day 07.05.20 or the dividend payout 9,600000000 EUR, and put them into a list.
This is just a part from the output I'm looking for:

```
      ISIN      ex-day     dividend payout     dividend frequencies payment period  shareholders meeting
0   DE0008404005  07.05.20  9,600000000 EUR   Laufende Dividende     Geschäftsjahr    06.05.20
1   DE0008404005  09.05.19  9,000000000 EUR   Laufende Dividende     Geschäftsjahr    08.05.19
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q8cO.png)

Comment: It looks like each item has a different value, so item in this list is different and not the same item.  That being said though.  It looks like it is related to just the first 2 indexes, correct?   If so, just look at the text for each of those 2 items' divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to slice and dice the data using the length of the table headers.

```
isin_key = 'DE0008404005'

url = 'https://www.boersen-zeitung.de/index.php?li=24&l=0&isin={}'.format(isin_key)
html_content = requests.get(url).text
csvFile = open('Data.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table")
headers = table.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "headline11"})
Title_Row = []
for header in headers:
    Title_Row.append(header.text)

print(Title_Row)
writer.writerow(Title_Row)# writer header row
print(len(headers))
table_data = table.find_all('td', attrs={"class": "text"})
# Divide the table_data by the length of headers
row=[]
i=0
for data in table_data:
    row.append(data.text)
    i=i+1
    if i==len(headers):
        i=0
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row)
        row.clear()

csvFile.close()
```

Output:

```
['Ex-Tag', 'Dividende', 'Dividendenart', 'Zahlungszeitraum', 'Hauptversammlung']
5
['07.05.20', '9,600000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '06.05.20']
['09.05.19', '9,000000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '08.05.19']
['10.05.18', '8,000000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '09.05.18']
['04.05.17', '7,600000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '03.05.17']
['05.05.16', '7,300000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '04.05.16']
['07.05.15', '6,850000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '06.05.15']
['08.05.14', '5,300000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '07.05.14']
['08.05.13', '4,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '07.05.13']
['10.05.12', '4,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '09.05.12']
['05.05.11', '4,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '04.05.11']
['06.05.10', '4,100000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '05.05.10']
['30.04.09', '3,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '29.04.09']
['22.05.08', '5,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '21.05.08']
['03.05.07', '3,800000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '02.05.07']
['04.05.06', '2,000000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '03.05.06']
['05.05.05', '1,750000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '04.05.05']
['06.05.04', '1,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '05.05.04']
['30.04.03', '1,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '29.04.03']
['13.06.02', '1,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '12.06.02']
['12.07.01', '1,500000000 EUR', 'Laufende Dividende', 'Geschäftsjahr', '11.07.01']
```